# Create MariaDB cluster across 2 seperated OpenShift clusters

Tags: cluster, mariadb, galera, openshift-origin

Good day,

I am looking to create a MariaDB cluster in OpenShift/Kubernetes. The caveat, is that my cluster need to be ''spanned'' across 2 seperated OpenShift/Kubernetes clusters.

I am trying to wrap my head around on how to do that.

Doing so on VM is ''easy''... But across 2 separated OpenShift/K8s....

P.S: if there is another solution with MySQL, I am a taker...

Comment: Galera can be manually added on top of MySQL.  Probably simpler to use MariaDB, which comes with Galera.

Comment: This is the most useless comment on serverfault.......................

Comment: You mentioned clustering and asked about both MariaDB and MySQL.  So I pointed out a tradeoff between those two.

Comment: I did not asked about tradeoff, but a take on how to spin a MySQL/MariaDB cluster over 2 different K8s clusters. This is also why I specified that ''Doing so on VM is ''easy''... But across 2 separated OpenShift/K8s....''